# Printing A Diamond Shape In Java, Based On User Input

Tags: java

I have a problem with a program I am trying to write. A user inputs a positive odd integer, otherwise the program prompts the user until they do. When they do, the program prints a diamond shape corresponding to the user input.

I have this piece so far that prints the left hand diagonal of such a figure, but cannot figure out how to print the rest of it. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class DrawingProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the drawing program:");
        System.out.println("Please Input a Positive Odd Integer:");
        char userAnswer; 
        int userInput;
        userInput = keyboard.nextInt(); 
        if (userInput%2 == 0){
            System.out.println("That is not a Positive Odd Integer!");
        }

        else if (userInput < 0){
            System.out.println("That is not a Positive Odd Integer");

        }

        else if (userInput%2 == 1){
                for (int row = 1; row<= userInput; row++){
                    for (int col = 1; col<= userInput; col++ ){
                        if (row+col==userInput-1 )

                            System.out.print( "*");
                        else
                            System.out.print( " ");
            }
                System.out.print("\n");
        }

    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this even compile? This if-statement appears incomplete: `if (row+col==userInput-1 || )`. The right hand-side of the "or" conditions seems to be missing.

Comment: `if (row+col==userInput-1 || )` that part of your code won't compile

Comment: One piece of advice is to break down your problem, isolating the bit that doesn't work for you. In this example, the user input isn't relevant - just set your "input" to a fixed value, say, 5, and focus on the drawing of the diamond using that value. The parts (input and drawing) are basically independent.

Comment: Check out [Printing Diamond Pattern in Correct Format in Java using Recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798173/printing-diamond-pattern-in-correct-format-in-java-using-recursion). i would recommend reading the accepted answer as it gives a great explanation :-)

Comment: Or you can get more info by just doing a Google search for "java print diamond pattern". I am only recommending doing that so you can see all the other answers provided already instead of hoping to get all of them in this question

Comment: Thank you Ascalonian and Andy for the help. For the rest of you; there is no reason to be hateful to a new subscriber. Had I known you would be this hateful, I probably would not have subscribed. A simple "you should do it like this.." or something along those lines would be more beneficial.

Comment: @MoparGuy there are *many* examples of the "you should do it like this" if you look in the related questions (to the side) or search first. Ignoring obvious duplicate questions may attract down votes. Some of these questions were presented to you as you typed the question. Additionally, you are expected to have something that at least compiles to be able to test for others to build off of. Posting code with syntax errors that won't compile puts extra work for people who are volunteering to help you to fix those errors (which you should have been able to fix before posting the code) also.

Comment: It is irrelevant at this point MichaelT- I am going to find a friendlier forum. I am a member of MANY different types of forums, and if a newbie makes a mistake, we don't ride their case- we simply tell them, and move on. Being hateful to newbies makes your forum as a whole look bad, and makes them want to go somewhere else- which is what i'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A user inputs a positive odd integer, otherwise the program prompts
>   the user until they do

You need to scan in a loop

```
do
{
    userInput = keyboard.nextInt(); 
    if (userInput % 2 == 0)
        System.out.println("That is not an Odd Integer!");            
    if(userInput < 0)
        System.out.println("That is not a Positive Odd Integer");
} while(userInput < 0 || userInput %2 == 0);
```

Now you can remove that validation `else if (userInput%2 == 1){`

Now the first thing I realize when checking at your loop is `if (row+col==userInput-1 || )` which won't compile as you have a comparison operator with nothing following.

Note that you can replace `System.out.print("\n");` with `System.out.println("")` but that's not really important...

Now replace your loop condition so that they start as 0

```
for (int row = 0; row <= userInput; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col <= userInput; col++ ){
```

Now since you want a Diamond, you need to have 4 diagonal, so 2 loops (one for top and bottom)...

```
for (int i = 1; i < userInput; i += 2)//Draw the top of the diamond
{
    for (int j = 0; j < userInput - 1 - i / 2; j++)//Output correct number of spaces before
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)//Output correct number of asterix
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    System.out.print("\n");//Skip to next line
}

for (int i = userInput; i > 0; i -= 2)//Draw the bottom of the diamond
{
    for (int j = 0; j < userInput -1 - i / 2; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

So the final code would look like this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the drawing program:");
    System.out.println("Please Input a Positive Odd Integer:");
    char userAnswer;
    int userInput;
    do
    {
        userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (userInput % 2 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("That is not an Odd Integer!");
        }
        if (userInput < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("That is not a Positive Odd Integer");
        }
    } while (userInput < 0 || userInput % 2 == 0);

    for (int i = 1; i < userInput; i += 2) //This is the number of iterations needed to print the top of diamond (from 1 to userInput by step of two for example with 5 = {1, 3, 5} so 3 rows.
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < userInput - 1 - i / 2; j++)//write correct number of spaces before, example with 5 = j < 5 - 1 -i / 2, so it would first print 4 spaces before, with 1 less untill it reach 0
        {
           System.out.print(" ");//write a space
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");//write an asterix
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }

    // Same logic apply here but backward as it is bottom of diamond
    for (int i = userInput; i > 0; i -= 2)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < userInput -1 - i / 2; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.print("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help- I tried this code, and it did not work. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You probably made a mistake when pasting, see edit I've pasted final main method.

Comment: @MoparGuy I edited to have 5 stars in the middle... Basically what we do here is simply loop from 1 to userInput by step of two to write line, then in each line, we display (userInput - 1 - i (row number) / 2) number of spaces before the asterix so we are centered. Then we display i occurence of asterix. The second loop simply repeat the same, but backward.

Comment: Thanks Jean- I had to tweak it a bit to get the result I needed, but the code works beautifully. Could you please explain the logical sequences you had to do as well? I am not just interested in the language, but the logic as well. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MoparGuy A `do..while` loop will iterate minimum one time until the final condition is met. So i first read from the scanner, then display error message if it not valid, then when the end of the loop is reached, the condition `while(userInput < 0 || userInput %2 == 0)` will re-iterate if the number is negative or not odd.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense. How did you go about figuring out how to actually print the diamond pattern? I'm still a bit confused on how you did it.

Comment: @MoparGuy Added comments in code to help you understand.

Comment: @MoparGuy if this answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark at the left of the answer.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again Jean